# Unable to install VMware kernel modules in Workstation 11 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, vmware

I am unable to install VMWare Workstation 11 successfully on Ubuntu 16.04 due to the Kernel Module Updater failing on the Virtual Machine Monitor and Virtual Network Device. Here is the log file that it tells me to look at:

```
2016-05-15T19:05:06.053+03:00| appLoader| I120: Log for appLoader pid=10156 version=11.0.0 build=build-2305329 option=Release
2016-05-15T19:05:06.053+03:00| appLoader| I120: The process is 64-bit.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.053+03:00| appLoader| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2016-05-15T19:05:06.053+03:00| appLoader| I120: Host is Linux 4.4.0-22-generic Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
2016-05-15T19:05:06.253+03:00| appLoader| I120: Invocation: "/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-gksu --sudo-mode --message=Please enter your password to proceed. '/usr/bin/vmware-modconfig' --icon='vmware-workstation' --appname='VMware'"
2016-05-15T19:05:06.253+03:00| appLoader| I120: Calling: "/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-gksu --sudo-mode --message=Please enter your password to proceed. '/usr/bin/vmware-modconfig' --icon='vmware-workstation' --appname='VMware'"
2016-05-15T19:05:06.253+03:00| appLoader| I120: VMDEVEL not set.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.253+03:00| appLoader| I120: VMWARE_SHIPPED_LIBS_LIST is not set.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.253+03:00| appLoader| I120: VMWARE_SYSTEM_LIBS_LIST is not set.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.253+03:00| appLoader| I120: VMWARE_USE_SHIPPED_LIBS is not set.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.253+03:00| appLoader| I120: VMWARE_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS is not set.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.253+03:00| appLoader| I120: Using configuration file /etc/vmware/config.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.254+03:00| appLoader| I120: Using library directory:  /usr/lib/vmware.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.255+03:00| appLoader| I120: Shipped glib version is 2.24
2016-05-15T19:05:06.255+03:00| appLoader| I120: System glib version is 2.48
2016-05-15T19:05:06.255+03:00| appLoader| I120: Using system version of glib.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.255+03:00| appLoader| I120: Detected VMware library libvmware-gksu.so.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.255+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libvmware-gksu.so node as SHIPPED.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.255+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgksu2.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.255+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.255+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgtop-2.0.so.7 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.255+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libglib-2.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.255+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXau.so.6 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgthread-2.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgmodule-2.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgobject-2.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libfontconfig.so.1 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libz.so.1 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libfreetype.so.6 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libpango-1.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgio-2.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libcairo.so.2 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libatk-1.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXfixes.so.3 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXdamage.so.1 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXcomposite.so.1 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXcursor.so.1 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXinerama.so.1 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXrender.so.1 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.256+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.257+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libpng12.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.257+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libpixman-1.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.257+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libexpat.so.0 node as INVALID.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.272+03:00| appLoader| I120: Created dependency tree.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.292+03:00| appLoader| I120: Accessibility is not enabled.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.314+03:00| appLoader| I120: Accessibility is not enabled.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.314+03:00| appLoader| I120: -- Processing libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 --
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: GTK: gtk_major_version: Comparing 2 with 2
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: GTK: gtk_minor_version: Comparing 24 with 20
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 validator returned true.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: -- Finished processing libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 --
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: -- Processing libglib-2.0.so.0 --
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: GLib: glib_major_version: Comparing 2 with 2
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: GLib: glib_minor_version: Comparing 48 with 48
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: libglib-2.0.so.0 validator returned true.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libglib-2.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: -- Finished processing libglib-2.0.so.0 --
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgksu2.so.0 node as SHIPPED.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgtop-2.0.so.7 node as SHIPPED.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.321+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXau.so.6 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.322+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.322+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.322+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libcairo.so.2 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.322+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libpixman-1.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.322+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libfontconfig.so.1 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.322+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libfreetype.so.6 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libz.so.1 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libexpat.so.0 node as SHIPPED.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libpng12.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXrender.so.1 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libpango-1.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgobject-2.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgthread-2.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgmodule-2.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXinerama.so.1 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.323+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXcursor.so.1 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXfixes.so.3 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXcomposite.so.1 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libXdamage.so.1 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libgio-2.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: Marking libatk-1.0.so.0 node as SYSTEM.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libXfixes.so.3 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libgobject-2.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libgmodule-2.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libvmware-gksu.so 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libgthread-2.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libXdamage.so.1 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libXcomposite.so.1 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libpixman-1.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libpango-1.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libcairo.so.2 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libgio-2.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libXrender.so.1 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libXinerama.so.1 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libgksu2.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libgtop-2.0.so.7 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libglib-2.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libXau.so.6 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libXcursor.so.1 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libz.so.1 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libfreetype.so.6 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libfontconfig.so.1 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libexpat.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libpng12.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.324+03:00| appLoader| I120: libatk-1.0.so.0 
2016-05-15T19:05:06.327+03:00| appLoader| I120: Shipped glib version is 2.24
2016-05-15T19:05:06.328+03:00| appLoader| I120: System glib version is 2.48
2016-05-15T19:05:06.328+03:00| appLoader| I120: Using system version of glib.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.328+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libXau.so.6.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.328+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libglib-2.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.328+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading shipped version of libgtop-2.0.so.7.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.328+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libpixman-1.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.328+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libz.so.1.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.328+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libfreetype.so.6.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.329+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading shipped version of libexpat.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.329+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libfontconfig.so.1.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.329+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libpng12.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.329+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libXrender.so.1.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.330+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libcairo.so.2.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.330+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libgthread-2.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.330+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libgobject-2.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.331+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libgmodule-2.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.331+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libpango-1.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.332+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.332+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.332+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libXinerama.so.1.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.333+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libXfixes.so.3.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.333+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libXcursor.so.1.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.333+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libXcomposite.so.1.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.333+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libXdamage.so.1.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.333+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libgio-2.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.334+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.334+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.335+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libatk-1.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.335+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.
2016-05-15T19:05:06.336+03:00| appLoader| I120: Loading shipped version of libgksu2.so.0.
```

From what I can see it seems to have some files missing or something.